# How to decide which port to use in socket communcation

Tags: java, sockets, port, ipc

I have to write a `Socket` communication program to implement
Inter Process Communication.

I understand I need to have a client and server implementation.
Server implementation:

```
MyServerice = new ServerSocket(PortNumber);
```

Client and server will be on same machine so I don't want to interfere with any other running applications

How to decide which port number to use?

Comment: Usually I search on google for the port number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)
those are mostly all, you will never know if any other external app is taking the port you have in mind, so in your case is a

***Firt to come, first to serve*** issue

Comment: i think i will try with 1024 as port number since 1023 is maximum

Answer (score 1):

I think in implementing the websocket object, the WebSocket protocol communications typically use TCP port number 80, so environments that block non-standard internet connections by using a firewall will still pass WebSocket packets.